# Bootstrap Icons の Code Point とは何か？

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### 問題の要約

Bootstrap Icons のページからアイコンの情報を見ると，次のような画面が表示されます．

[image]

Code point とは何のことでしょうか？

Unicode や CSS や JS, HTML などと書かれていますが，これをそのまま書いても当然ながら反映されるわけではありません．

どのような使い方を想定したものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

CSS だけ，使い方がわかりました．

まず CDN を読み込んで Bootstrap Icons が使用できるようにしておきます．

CSS の中で `fontfamily` に `Bootstrap-icons` を指定したうえで，`content` に CSS の Code point を指定します．つまり，`head` 要素の中に次のようなHTMLを書きます．

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<style>
    h3::before {
        font-family:'Bootstrap-icons';
        content:'\F120';
    }
</style>
```

そうすると，指定した通り `h3` 要素にアイコンが表示されていることがわかります．

CSS以外の Code point については，まだ調査中です．